# easiest tool to use for a extreme beginner for classification/clustering

Tags: classification

I saw that the tool weka is having a gui interface. This gui interface is very easy for non coding users to classify data sets into classes. Matlab is very difficult since say for example making a neural network you need to write code and to do that you need to have a solid understanding of whats going on. Are there other tools like weka or else is there a plugin to matlab that gives more power to it?

Answer (score 2):

RapidMiner has a functional GUI, and will work for both classification and clustering. It is the most popular open-source (free) data mining application available as of 2012.

RapidMiner: http://rapid-i.com/

It also has numerous training videos and tutorials that you can follow along with - I learned basic clustering methods using a K-means cluster method in about 3 hours. See the Vancouver Data blog for some great RapidMiner analytics videos. Top-notch stuff, really.

Vancouver Data (Neil McGuigan): http://vancouverdata.blogspot.com/

As a bonus, you can install the Weka plug-in, which then gives you GUI Weka. All of the add-ons are free and well-integrated. Other add-ons include a GUI 'R' (the stats program), Reporting Services, Text and Web Analytics, etc. It is fairly simple to use straight 'out of the box' (IMO).

Comment: is a Hidden Markov Model also implemented?

Comment: HMM plugins for RapidMiner are available here: http://hector.cs.ucf.edu/teamwork/?page_id=86 and here: http://code.google.com/p/rapidminerhmm/. I haven't evaluated these plugins, as a FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Weka is very (very) powerful and you can write your own classifier if that's what you need to do.

Between Matlab and Weka there's pretty much nothing you can't do in terms of Machine Learning.

You might want to check out Netlab toolkit for Matlab, which is a neural network toolkit developed by a Professor at Aston University - it is available from http://www1.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/